# testing WebSocket

Tags: java, spring, websocket, spring-websocket

подскажите пожалуйста, как можно протестить вебсокет?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
@Order(HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

private final Object1 object1;
private final Object2 object2;

@Value("${thread.count}")
private Integer THREADS;

public WebSocketConfig(Object1 object1, Object2 object2) {
    this.object1= object1;
    this.object2= object2;
}

@Override
public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addHandler(new WebSocketSummaryHandler(object1, object2, THREADS), "websocket/summary").setAllowedOrigins("*");
}
}



@ComponentScan
public class WebSocketSummaryHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {

private final Object1 object1;
private final Object2 object2;

private Integer threads;

public WebSocketSummaryHandler(Object1 object1, Object2 object2, Integer threads) {
    this.object1 = object1;
    this.object2 = object2;
    this.threads = threads;
}
@Override
public void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage messageRequest) {
  //реализация
}
}
```

гугл подсказал вот такой вот вариант, но он у меня не работает:

```
@ClientEndpoint
public class TestWebSocketClient {
 Session session;

 @OnOpen
 public void onOpen(final Session session){
    this.session = session;
 }
}


@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("IntegrationTest")
@TestPropertySource(properties = "spring.config.location=file:./src/main/configs/application.properties")
@SpringBootTest
public class WebSocketTest {
 private WebSocketContainer container;
 private TestWebSocketClient client;

 @Before
 public void init(){
  container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
  client = new TestWebSocketClient();
 }
 @Test
 public void test()
 {
  container.connectToServer(client, URI.create("ws://localhost:9010/websocket/summary"));
 }
}
```

при дебаге

container.connectToServer(client, URI.create("ws://localhost:9010/websocket/summary"));

выдает вот такую ошибку:

The HTTP request to initiate the WebSocket connection failed

предположение, что я не к тому порту стучусь, хотя в пропертях проставлен 9010

Answer (score 0):

может кому то поможет:

ссылка на [книгу](https://books.google.ru/books?id=nIF8DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA107&lpg=PA107&dq=handleTextMessage%20test&source=bl&ots=LXzZR_wFO_&sig=ACfU3U0u21V-X53UIEk6hFkZsVNC3Q0nuw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi-qerOo-PpAhXmw8QBHQbWCawQ6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=handleTextMessage%20test&f=false)

ссылка на спринговые [тесты](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-websocket/src/test/java/org/springframework/web/socket/client/standard/StandardWebSocketClientTests.java) ВебСоккетов